# How can I get the value of a bar chart label when clicked in ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I want to get the value of the label when clicked on a bar chart in Angular JS. I have the html template:

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="data"
                                 chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="true"  height="350"
                                chart-series="series" chart-click="onClick"> 
</canvas>
```

here is my JS for the click event:

```
$scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
                                console.log("Chart clicked", points, evt);
                                console.log(points);
                                if(points.length > 0){
                                    console.log("Bar chart clicked");
                                    console.log("Point", points[0].value);

                                }
                              };
```

What I want to do is to display the value of the label when clicked on a bar chart, more specifically I want to get the value of _model -> label. Below is a picture of what gets printed in the console.[image]

This line: `console.log("Point", points[0].value);` returns undefined.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: cant you just access points[0].label?

Comment: from the console it looks like you are using this library to draw your charts: https://www.chartjs.org, is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Try including the third variable in the `$scope.onClick` callback, which gets defined when you click a particular bar.

In the HTML:

```
<canvas id="bar" 
        ... other stuff ...
        chart-click="ctrl.onClick">
</canvas>
```

In the controller:

```
ctrl.onClick = function(_points, _event, barClicked) {
  if (barClicked) {
    var associatedLabel = barClicked._model.datasetLabel;
    console.log("Label of the bar you clicked is " + associatedLabel);
  }
}
```

I was rendering multiple bars per `year` along the X-axis and originally used just the two callback variables, but all `_points` was giving me was all the chart elements within the year I clicked. The above gave me the exact bar I clicked.

I couldn't find this in the ChartJS docs, so I'm not sure if it is applicable in all cases, but it worked wonders for me. Cheers!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but how did you get the barClicked to get passed into the function??

Comment: `barClicked` is a parameter accessible in the `chart-click` callback - it's passed into the function by default. I called it `barClicked` but you can name it anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$scope.onClick = function (points, e, instance) {
    $scope.chart = instance._chart;
    $scope.activeElement = $scope.chart.getElementAtEvent(e);        
    console.log(points[0]._chart.data.datasets[$scope.activeElement[0]._datasetIndex].data[$scope.activeElement[0]._index] );
};
```

Comment: yes, that is right `window.myPieChart.data.labels[chartElements[0].index];` like this