# Click on interactive chart.js bar chart and get value for labels and groups in JS

Tags: javascript, python, onclick, chart.js, bar-chart

I'm building an webapp where you choose airline companies and get a bar chart with scores in five categories(company, food, luggage, punctuality, staff). I want to get a value for company name and category, when a user clicks different parts of the chart. It's to do further things in Python using the values for company name and category.

For example, in the image below, when a user clicks the big green bar(fourth bar from the right), I want my JS to receive `company="Air France", category="punctuality"`. I assume I need to do something with `onclick` but cannot figure out...

[image]

Context: Based on the companies you choose in the form box, a Python backend returns a json data to JS. In JS `addGroupBarChart` draws a chart using Chart.js and embeds it in the canvas element in html.

This is an excerpt from JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(){
/* returns the companies value chosen from the dropdown */
/* and draw a chart using addGroupBarChart function */
    let companies = $("#companies").val();
    let headers = new Headers()
    let init = {
        method : 'GET',
        headers : headers
    }
    let params = {
        'companies':companies
    }

    let url = getWebAppBackendUrl('/get_stats')+'/'+JSON.stringify(params)
    let promise = fetch(url, init) 
                   .then(function(response){
                       response.json()
                               .then(function(data){
                                addGroupBarChart(data.barChartGroup.company, 
                                                 data.barChartGroup.labels);
                                })
                   });
}


document.getElementById("bar-chart-group").onclick = function(......) {
/* returns the company and category chosen from the chart */
/* this is the function I don't know how to build */
    let activePoints = // here I assume I need getPointsAtEvent(evt) but not sure...
    let company = // company value based on the click on the chart
    let category = // category value based on the click on the chart
    let headers = new Headers()
    let init = {
        method : 'GET',
        headers : headers
    }
    let params = {
        'company':company,
        'category':category
    }

    let url = getWebAppBackendUrl('/get_table')+'/'+JSON.stringify(params)
    let promise = fetch(url, init) 
                   .then(function(response) {
                       response.json()
                       .then(function(data){
                           // function to add table
                       })
                   });
}


function addGroupBarChart(data, labels) {
/* function to add a bar chart using the data returned from Python backend */
    document.getElementById('bar-card').innerHTML = '<canvas id="bar-chart-group" chart-click="onClick"></canvas>';
    i = 1
    arr = []
    data.forEach(function(d){
        company = Object.keys(d);
        values = d[company]['data'];
        dataset_company = {
            label:company,
            backgroundColor: default_colors[i],
            data:values};
        console.log("dataset_company", dataset_company);
        arr.push(dataset_company);
        i+=1;
    })

    let data_grouped = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: arr
              };

    new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-group"), {
        type: "bar",
        data: data_grouped,
        options: {
          title: {
            display: false,
            text: "Sentiment by category"
          }
        }
    });
}
```

`data` and `labels` arguments that go into `addGroupBarChart` looks like

```
data = [{"Air France":{"data":[0.1, -0.2, 0.3, -0.1, 0.1]}}, 
        {"Lufthansa":{"data":[0.3, -0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1]}}]

labels = ["company", "food", "luggage", "punctuality", "staff"]
```

I tried several solutions including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768091/chartjs-get-value-of-label-when-clicked-on-bar-chart) one, but it made my app not show the chart even after clicking "Show chart" button. I started learning JS last week so quite noob... Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define an [`onClick`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/events.html) event handler, which unfortunately is poorly documented. In your case, it would look as follows, `onBarClicked` being your own function that is invoked with `company` and `category`.

```
options: {
  ...
  onClick: event => {
    const datasetIndex = chart.getElementAtEvent(event)[0]._datasetIndex;
    const model = chart.getElementsAtEvent(event)[datasetIndex]._model;
    onBarClicked(model.datasetLabel, model.label);
  }
}
```

Please have a look at your amended code below:

```js
function onBarClicked(company, category) {
  console.log('company = ' + company + ", category = " + category);
}

const default_colors = ['green', 'blue'];
function addGroupBarChart(data, labels) {
  arr = []
  data.forEach((d, i) => {
    company = Object.keys(d)[0];
    values = d[company]['data'];
    dataset_company = {
      label: company,
      backgroundColor: default_colors[i],
      data: values
    };
    arr.push(dataset_company);
  });

  let data_grouped = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: arr
  };

  var chart = new Chart("bar-chart-group", {
    type: "bar",
    data: data_grouped,
    options: {
      title: {
        display: false,
        text: "Sentiment by category"
      },
      onClick: event => {
        const datasetIndex = chart.getElementAtEvent(event)[0]._datasetIndex;
        const model = chart.getElementsAtEvent(event)[datasetIndex]._model;
        onBarClicked(model.datasetLabel, model.label);
      }
    }
  });
}

const data = [{"Air France":{"data":[0.1, -0.2, 0.3, -0.1, 0.1]}}, 
        {"Lufthansa":{"data":[0.3, -0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1]}}];
const labels = ["company", "food", "luggage", "punctuality", "staff"];
addGroupBarChart(data, labels);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="bar-chart-group" height="80"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the new version of Chart.js, the below code would work.

```
const ctx = $('#monitor');
monitorChart = new Chart(ctx, config);

ctx.on('click', function(evt) {
  const points = monitorChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true);

  if (points.length) {
    const firstPoint = points[0];
    const label = monitorChart.data.labels[firstPoint.index];
    const slabel = monitorChart.data.datasets[firstPoint.datasetIndex].label;
    const value = monitorChart.data.datasets[firstPoint.datasetIndex].data[firstPoint.index];
    console.log(label, slabel, value);
  }
});
```

You can check [Here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getelementsateventformode-e-mode-options-usefinalposition)!

Answer (score 0):

the answer of @risingagain seems to be made for jquery.
for vanillajs, as per the actual [documentation at](https://%22Handling%20onClick%20Events%20on%20ChartJS%20Bar%20Charts%20-%20Mastering%20JS%22%20https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/chartjs/onclick-bar-chart) , the event should stay on the canvas element itself, so i'll rewrite his (otherwise working) example:

```
const ctx = $('#monitor');
let chart = new Chart(ctx, config);                  
chart.ctx.canvas.onclick = (evt) => {
    const points = chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true);
                        
    if (points.length) {
        const firstPoint = points[0];
        const label = chart.data.labels[firstPoint.index];
        const slabel = chart.data.datasets[firstPoint.datasetIndex].label;
        const value = chart.data.datasets[firstPoint.datasetIndex].data[firstPoint.index];
                             
        console.log(label, slabel, value);
    }
};
```